Make the number 606 50 percent bigger
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification:  Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

The number 606 is written on a sheet of paper.  What operation must be performed to make the number 50% greater?

This puzzle is from the July/August 1992 issue of Quantum magazine.

I, for one, am disappointed with the down votes. The OP made it very clear that this is a beginner puzzle. It is a fun puzzle. On this site we should welcome puzzles with all kinds of flavor and difficulty. Not only very clever or complicated puzzles that need a lot of time and effort to solve. My 2 cents

@DrD Long time no see. I don’t think it is the difficulty rating, it seems way too open for competing interpretations and invites speculative responses that is why I think people have an issue with it.

It says "written on a paper". Also "what operation" not "operations". So it simply expects a very simple answer. Font size increase or adding things violates these rules I think. Answer like look thru a magnifying glass may be valid but that is the extent to which I would go.

rot13(zhygvcyvpngvba) is also an operation - and the question should probably exclude it.

@MaciejStachowski rot13(V guvax gur yngreny-guvaxvat gnt fubhyq or vagrecergrq nf rkpyhqvat zhygvcyvpngvba.  V nz ybbxvat sbe n guvaxvat bhgfvqr gur obk glcr nafjre.)

In music production, we could take one classic drum machine and add a computer controlled bass line, to get another classic drum machine. :)

@DrD I was reloading the page yesterday, when I noticed someone downvoted the all answers at once. And people are getting really pedantic on what constitutes "one" operation or not. For example, the cutting answer, is is a single operation? Or many, considering you have to use the scissors more than once. I think we should apply the rule of cool, instead of spreading grief on a fun puzzle.

That is a (Rule of) cool comment @MindwinRememberMonica

@RogerA the Tautology Club wants to invite you for a keynote. https://xkcd.com/703/

I'm pretty sure that "stretch" is not the intended answer.

This entertaining puzzle currently has 30 upvotes and 7 downvotes.  It seems as if the community consensus is that it is a worthwhile question.  I hope it gets reopened.

@WillOctagonGibson most of the up votes are likely not from the "community", they're from passerby on the HNQ that don't know what quality standards/rules this site has.

There were 3 people who voted to keep this question open, one of which has a reputation greater than 50k and another who has a reputation significantly greater than 50k.  They are part of this community.

The intended solution is quite obvious.  All answers aren't necessarily speculative.  If they are blatantly incorrect, they are usually deleted as such.  I understand curating that aspect can seem tedious, but having many answers doesn't necessarily mean it invites a speculative answer.

@MacGyver88 Here is the current problem: if I try to moderate the answers (e.g. flag, downvote, comment), then I am told that because they are funny they are OK. Which means that they are accepted. Then, since barely-fitting joke answers are accepted, I tried to moderate the question (closevote, comment), and then I am told that the problem is with the answers and I shouldn't do anything about the question. So which is it? Is there support for deleting joke answers? Then the question is fine. Is there no support for deleting joke answers? Then the question is insufficiently specified.

@bobble To answer your question, I always support deleting joke answers IF they are incorrect.  The reason I spoke up is because a metric for site creation in Area 51 is a large number of answers.  So if more than one answer is a problem, then why is it a necessary metric? It seems when there are a large number of answers, questions appear to almost always be closed as too broad, when the type of question itself supports many correct complete answers.  In that case, I believe it is the answerer's issue.

@MacGyver88 if you think the answers should be deleted, then vote in LQP (Low Quality Posts) Review.

@bobble I normally do when I log on and see the red dot.  I tend to skip the answers I know nothing about though. For example math problems and what-not.  I do the small part I feel comfortable doing.  I admire your ability to comfortably do a large part.  No question.  You are an important part of our community.

'50 percent greater' means

 the current value is increased by an additional half. In other words, the resulting value is 1.5 times bigger than the original value.

Hence the answer we are looking for is

 606×1.5=909

Since the number 606 is written on a sheet of paper, we can achieve the result by an operation called

 Rotation.


 (rotate the paper 180 degrees)


I would imagine that this was the intended solution when the puzzle was first published.  It's great to see the [tag:lateral-thinking] alternative answers, too.

Even pre-internet there were complicated ways to solve simple problems.

 Even then you could increase font size.


 You only needed the scissors tool.


 
 The operation is called cutting.


I wouldn't call that "greater", I would call it "bigger" or "larger".

@bobble the title of the question says "bigger", though

The sheet of paper with the number 606 is a check.

 Invest it on Argentina's economy for roughly 3 months.

Given that it had

 211% inflation rate in 2023, the 606 dollars will grow by ~50% in 3 months.

The operation is called,

 Compound Interest.


that was funny :)

This is clearly not in the spirit of the puzzle, and you are adding more non-insignificant qualities to the paper.

bobble here's the fun part. You can make any piece of paper a money order (a check), so long the bank agrees with you that it is a valid money order.

@bobble I think this answer is fine. It's hard to draw a line in lateral-thinking questions. For me this one is fine, while the Maga-ification is not fine.

Get two flat mirrors.

 Place them standing up on the paper reflective side facing the numbers, making a 90º angle between them, with the number 606 in the rectangle formed by extending the two mirrors. If you look in the correct way, you'll see the number 909 in the reflection of the two mirrors.

The operation is called:

 Reflection


You just need one mirror.

@dr_ no. Because with one miror in the vertical (sideways), the loops of the sixes will remain in the lower part. To make them nines, you need the second mirror to reflect them along the second axis. If you put the mirror in the horizontal (facing the viewer), then you'll have the nines backward.

Ah, yes. You're right. My mistake.

@dr_ NP. Have fun and thanks for participating.

Put the paper in one of those...

 ... Xerox [1] machines. Set the amplification rate to 150% and press the copy button.


 [1] No endorsement intended on either part.

The operation is called:

 Photocopy.


Draw a red hat on the numbers, with the saying:

 Make Arithmetics 150% Great Again.

The operation is called,

 Maga-ification. Though it might only work on imaginary numbers or if you put it in a radical expression. YMMV.


Make the number HUGE!  Best number you ever saw.  Trust me, I've seen a lot of numbers.

Isn't that called Trump-isation? Making things great again?

This is clearly not in the spirit of the puzzle.

@bobble, did you miss the [tag:lateral-thinking] at the foot of the question?  For one, I'm enjoying the creative answers outside the "spirit" of the original.

Sorry for the downvote, but I did it since it doesn't explain why the number 606 specifically was chosen

@oAlt beside being the number in the puzzle? No real reason. But think about that, most answers work on any number. They are more valuable than the specific ones. You might as well go and downvote most of the answers here, since most of them just assume they should use 606.

As for me, it shouldn't work for any number, because the puzzle specifically stated 606. The solver simply follows the rules of the puzzle setter, not the other way round. Also I wouldn't downvote the others because they don't bring very unrelated details into the answer. E.g. take Retudin's. Yes, his answer doesn't justify 606 either. But as paper is a material that can be divided into pieces, it shows that he stuck closer to the details of the puzzle, so I wouldn't really downvote it.

Yes, you can bring rot13(gur pnc) into your answer, and it is technically correct and it uses lateral thinking, but it was introduced out of nowhere. There are details that can be used that are more relevant to the puzzle. I think there comes a point where one thinks too outside the box and has to come a bit closer to the box.

Moving. In particular, bringing the piece of paper closer to your eyes.


 On the other side of the paper, write "606" using figures 50% larger than on the first side.


It speaks of one operation.

It's a two-part operation.
